I installed OpenJDK 22 on Ubuntu (with 'Software'), but where?
I use Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. I opened 'Software', found OpenJDK ver. 22.0.1 and pressed Install. But where did it get installed?
I need to direct GradleW, a part of Python-Kivy-Buildozer (and Android Studio), to use it instead of JDK 11, which is located here: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Thank you. :-)
Addition:
I did a thorough search for folders containing 'openjdk', and the only ones from today, when I installed the new OpenJDK, were these:


This question is no longer relevant, because of this:
I have - at least partly - solved this. :-)
On https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users#unsupported-class-file-major-version-62 I read:
"The Java version used by p4a is the version required for the gradle version used. This can be any version between openJDK-11 and 17, the install instructions suggest 17."
Then I did this Java install:
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk
(Inspired by this: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/master/docs/source/installation.rst#android-on-ubuntu-2004-and-2204-64bit
Then 'buildozer android debug deploy run' could compile.
So I no longer need the OpenJDK ver. 22.
